# Question on the proof of completeness of the space of square integrable martingales - using uniform convergence in probability to find a limit

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Below is a lemma from Ikeda Watanabe's Stochastic Differential Equations that the space of right continuous square integrable martingales is complete under the metric specified below.

In the middle of the proof, I don't know why we get $E[|X_t^n - X_t|^2] \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ from $\sup_{t \le T}|X_t^n - X_t|\to 0$ in probability.

Since we have for any natural number $T$, $E[|X_T^n - X_T^m|^2] \to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty$, and $|X_T^n - X_T^m|^2$ is a submartingale in time, we get $E[|X_t^n - X_t^m|^2] \to 0$ for any $t\le T$. Now by the completeness of $L^2$, we can get a $L^2$ limit $X_t$.

However, my argument does not use the uniform convergence in probability of $X^n \to X$.

How is this condition used in the proof here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't that just Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem? You exchange the limit with the expectation (integral in $dP$)

Comment: @G.Gare How do we dominate the sequence? And we have convergence in probability so should use Vitali's convergence theorem instead. But we still need a $L^2$ bound for $|X_t^n - X_t|$.